# Running Java in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: java, internet-explorer, applet

I have JRE 8u211 installed on a Windows 10 box with IE 11.  I can see the Java plugin (and plugin 2) are installed and enabled.  I have the "Allow active content to run in files on my computer" option checked under Security.  But I cannot get a Java applet to load.  Every time the page loads, I get the "The page you are viewing uses Java" notification as if the browser thinks I don't have Java installed.

What am I missing?

Comment: Applets are **dead**. Really **dead**.

Comment: I read "The page you are viewing uses Java" not as information that Java is not installed, but as a *warning* that the page is trying to use Java, and since Java is not safe, you shouldn't do that. In order to run the Java, you'd likely have to relax the security settings of IE (not a good idea).

Comment: When the browser has a security issue with Java (say, when the zone policy is set super strict), the browser will explicitly state that the content is being blocked.  I'd forgotten that IE traditionally doesn't play well with x64 Java installs or even recognize they're installed.  After plopping on the 32 bit version, everything worked - after the requisite 30 million popup warnings asking me if I'm **sure** I want to do this horrible thing of course ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Figured it out.  I'd forgotten that IE traditionally doesn't seem to like x64 Java installs very much.  Once I dropped a 32 bit version, everything worked.

In the perfect dream world where all software development makes use of current and best practices, applets might be dead.  But in the actual world of legacy support, they are (unfortunately) still alive.

Comment: I had multiple versions of JRE so I uninstalled all other versions than one JRE 32-bit version. Ensure that the Java control panel refers to 32-bit JRE only.

Answer (score 4):

I second the comment by Elliot Fischer... However, there is still quite a lot of Hardware that is still being supported, or even potentially manufactured (sold for sure) that can only function with these Java applets.

I had this problem with my Motorola FX7400. Of course Motorola says it's "Service & Support Discontinuation Date" is 30.8.2019. Of course the latest firmware is from 2015 and doesn't have a hint of any type of certificate or signing of java applets!

For most applets that have not been updated since the very latest Java Security settings were upgraded in around 2013-2015 and which most likely are also only 32-bit and have no signing of any sort on them; Do the following steps. **Of course, even I CANNOT RECOMMEND THIS METHOD AT ALL FOR APPLICATIONS RUN FROM THE INTERNET** Also, you should take precautions when trying to use Java like this on Hardware you are not familiar with.

The steps that are required for Windows 7, 8.1 & 10 with Internet Explorer 11 are as follows:

- Download and install latest **JRE SE 32bit** from here: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html (And yes, you need to give out your private data including address and phone number. You also need to pay for a license, if you are not a developer or a private user)
- Start Internet Explorer 11 (64 bit seems to work fine)
- Ensure ActiveX filtering is disabled `Tools -> ActiveX filtering` On my install disabling this was only necessary to be able to run the Java test from the `"alternate page"`, which is marked "**IE 11 users:**": https://www.java.com/en/download/installed.jsp
- Check that the Java plugin is enabled `Tools -> Manage Add-ons`
- Check that your security zone has `Scripting of Java applets` enabled. On my IE11 it was enabled by default even for the Internet-zone set to Medium-High with protected mode on `Tools -> Internet Options -> Security -> (select your appropriate zone) -> Custom level -> Scripting of Java applets`
- If the applet that needs to run is not properly signed (very likely...), it is required to set every single URL where an applet is run in to the exceptions. (As of writing this answer, at least wildcars for paths are working.)
- When running the applet, accept the security exception prompts that Java prompts for.
- And finally! For some reason there will at some point when loading an applet that previously loaded fine be a prompt about not being able to run the applet, because only applications that meet the very high security settings (signed applets) can be run. To get back to running again, Java's temporary files need to be removed. Restoring security prompts has no effect. `Start Menu -> Configure Java -> General tab -> Temporary Internet Files -> Settings... -> Delete Files -> OK` `C:\Users\%username%\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\Cache` -directory probably also works.

Security and prompts really have come far in the past 10 years, haven't they?

Answer (score 1):

I jumped here searching for an answer that I found elsewhere and I would like to share.

According to my experience  the problems of IEx64 with jre x64 are due to the fact that internet explorer tabs are 32 bit processes, so they work only if they find a 32 bit jre. There is a registry key to force IEx64 to open x64 tabs:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main
Dword TabProcGrowth set to 0
```

I heard it is considered a security flaw, but it can be accepted if IE is used only with well known legacy web applications.

**About IEx64**

In the folder

```
\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer
```

there is the 32 bit version and when you open a page in IEx64 it is actually displayed by an new instance of IEx86. You can check this using task manager, going on detail tab and looking at the application path.